# Can't add item to custom arrayadapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to get this to add and nothing happens at all. I have made adjustments to my arrrayadapter and it should work.

```
public class TaskTracker extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button addButton;
    addButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ListView myListView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final EditText myEditText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
    //this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row));


    final ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    //this.setListAdapter(new TTAdapterView(this,items));
    final TTAdapterView aa = new TTAdapterView(this,items);
    //final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>( 
   // aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0);
    //myListView.setAdapter(aa);


    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            aa.add(myEditText.getText().toString());
            //taskitems.add(count, myEditText.getText().toString());
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myEditText.setText("");
            myEditText.requestFocus();
                                        }
    });
}
}

public class TTAdapterView extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context1;
private final ArrayList<String> items;

public TTAdapterView(Activity context, ArrayList<String> items){
    super(context,R.layout.row,items);
    this.context1 = context;
    this.items = items;
}
static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView task;
    public Chronometer time;
    public CheckBox complete;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;

    if(rowView==null){
        LayoutInflater vi = context1.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.task = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.time = (Chronometer) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
        holder.complete = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    return rowView;
}

}
```

Any idea as to why its not updating?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer is right,,

```
String taskText=items.get(position); 
holder.task.setText(taskText);
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set content for your rows in the listview -_-!

At least you should do this inside getView:

```
String taskText=items.get(position); 
holder.task.setText(taskText);
```

Comment: Should I do the onclick for my add button inside the getView?

Comment: @user695156 no,just keep the add button outside the getView.

Comment: Please check this http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/  a very nice tutorial for Custom ListView

Comment: I did this and still got nothing showing up in my listview activity.

Comment: @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
  
  ViewHolder holder;
  View rowView = convertView;
  
  if(rowView==null){
   LayoutInflater vi = context1.getLayoutInflater();
   rowView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.task = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   holder.time = (Chronometer) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
   holder.complete = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
 String taskText = items.get(position);
 holder.task.setText(taskText);
 rowView.setTag(holder);